# Pyttsx can't convert text to apeech

Tags: python, text-to-speech, pyttsx

I have following piece of code. Which does the text to speech conversion using pyttsx.

```
sys.stdout.write("> ")
#sys.stdout.flush()
classify(sentence = sys.stdin.readline())
while True:
    sentence = sys.stdin.readline()      #input sentence
    text = response(sentence)     #response to the input sentence.
    engine = pyttsx3.init()
    rate = engine.getProperty('rate')
    engine.setProperty('rate', rate - 5)
    engine.say(text)     #converts the text to speech
    engine.runAndWait()
```

It plays the sound saying 'None'. The response text is printed on the console but speech module speaks nothing other than 'None'. Why is so? I have tried the code as follows too:

```
sys.stdout.write("> ")
    #sys.stdout.flush()
    classify(sentence = sys.stdin.readline())
    while True:
        sentence = sys.stdin.readline()      #input sentence
        response(sentence)     #response to the input sentence.
        engine = pyttsx3.init()
        rate = engine.getProperty('rate')
        engine.setProperty('rate', rate - 5)
        engine.say(response(sentence))     #converts the text to speech
        engine.runAndWait()
```

But that doesn't seem to work either. Where am I making a mistake while passing argument into `engine.say()` string?
Because when I write `engine.say('I'm working.')`, it speaks and reads out the phrase, while printing the response text.

```
def response(sentence, userID='123', show_details=False):
    # if we have a classification then find the matching intent tag
    if results:
        # loop as long as there are matches to process
        while results:

            for i in intents['intents']:

                # find a tag matching the first result
               if i['tag'] == results[0][0]:
                    # set context for this intent if necessary
                    if 'context_set' in i:
                        if show_details: print ('context:', i['context_set'])
                        context[userID] = i['context_set']

                    # check if this intent is contextual and applies to this user's conversation
                    if not 'context_filter' in i or \
                        (userID in context and 'context_filter' in i and i['context_filter'] == context[userID]):
                        if show_details: print ('tag:', i['tag'])
                        # a random response from the intent
                        return print(random.choice(i['responses']))

            results.pop(0)
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't show us your `response()` function, but it's clearly returning `None`.

This is what's causing the behaviour you're describing.

Comment: Thanks for your response

I have now added the function. I tried to add Return " "+response(sentence). It didn't work. I did it wrong I suppose. Can you help me figure out what should it return and what should I put in the engine.say(), so it speaks for me?